# Nginx on dockers getting 404 error on refresh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker, nginx

I am getting 404 errors on refresh with other headers. I never work with nginx before.  Anyone can advice how to fix this error? I try multiple solution like adding try_files $uri /index.html; to the localtion / but it doesnt work.

My frontend,backend,database and proxy server is running dockers.

This is my nginx default.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
client_max_body_size 10M;

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://server:5000/api;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
location / {
    root /source;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

}

this is my docker-compose.yml. Do i need to shared volume for frontend, backend, nginx too?

```
version: '3'

services:

  client:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Production
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    links:
      - server
    depends_on:
      - server
    volumes:
      - shared:/app

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - shared:/data/db

  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.Production
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - shared:/app
    expose:
      - 5000

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Singapore
    links:
      - server
    depends_on:
      - server
      - client
    volumes:
      - shared:/app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

volumes:
  shared:
```

Comment: You should provide more info. Which links does return 404? Does dockered nginx log request?

Comment: any links beside,  localhost:80.

localhost:80/<header> all return 404

how do you log the request??

Comment: Did you try `localhost:8080`?, because your nginx is listening on port 8080 and your client service is using the port 80. If your client service isn't serving a webserver, your configuration isn't going to work for any outside client.

Comment: Look inside docker at /var/log/nginx/access.log

Comment: there is nothing in the access.log

Comment: Then you dont hit dockered nginx